# React Native Windows App Loading Error (80072f78)

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, react-native, react-native-windows

I'm new to react and react-native, and am attempting to run the react-native-windows template project but have encountered an issue.

**Error**

App loads in a blank window with error banner `Error 80072f78 downloading http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=windows&dev=true&hot=false&inlineSourceMap=true`

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBnbS.png)

**What I've Tried**

I followed the instructions on the react-native-windows [getting started docs](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/getting-started)

Namely:

```
npx react-native init <projectName> --template react-native@^0.63.2
cd projectName
npx react-native-windows-init --overwrite
npx react-native run-windows
```

The process will start another terminal window with the react logo.  The application will build successfully, and will start in a new window.  However, the original error is always present.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling all relevant programs.  I've also tried building in both c# and c++, to no avail (adding the --language flag in the third step above).

**Versions**

react-native-windows: *0.63*
react-native: *0.63.2*
Windows SDK: 10.0.18362.0
node: *14.16.0*
npm: *6.14.11*

I couldn't find any issues like this online.  If anyone has a suggestion, I would appreciate it.  I'm more than happy to provide further info.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have connection issue which sometimes occurs when you do a windows update. I know you aren't doing an update, but it looks like trying some of the fixes at the posting may help : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-error-code-80072f78/10f0d975-094c-4948-aa75-3f963eb1cb0f

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for the answer!  I tried the posted solutions and, while the troubleshooter did detect an issue with windows updates, I'm at the mercy of my organization when it comes to updating my os version (due to privacy rules I assume). Still weird to me that a windows update issue would interfere with react native windows, especially considering I'm using the correct windows SDK version...

Comment: I think you should be using npm (not npx.See : https://github.com/ModernJavaScriptDevelopment/ModernJavaScriptDevelopment/issues/1.  How long does it take for failure to occur?  If error is around 30 seconds it may be a proxy issue.  What also bothers me is the link is showing HTTP and not HTTPS (secure which uses TLS).  This may be an issue where server want HTTPS and you are sending HTTP.

Comment: I would think so as well but it built fine on my personal laptop, making me think there is some low level issue here.  The error is instant - the react native docs say `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/` should have a debug menu, so I think this process just uses http.  I am currently trying to make react-native-windows check another port for the bundle... no success yet.

Comment: Everybody is having issues with HTTPS.  There are a lot of different combinations of issues.  Before Net 4.7.2 the TLS is only done in Net and depending on version of TLS (1.0,1.0,1.1,1.2) and the encryption mode failures were often occurring because Net didn't support all the modes.  Then start 4.7.2 you have a choice in the config file to use either the operating system or net for TLS.  Then if you are using the operating system you have to make sure on mobile device that the kernel was update to support the TLS version and encryption mode.

Comment: Five years ago the industry decided to obsolete TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1due to hackers being able to decrypt messages and requiring TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3.  Last June Microsoft did a push on servers to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1.  Client could still send TLS but the server were refusing the connection.  A lot of old code broke where clients were still requesting 1.0 or 1.1. Often 1.0 or 1.1 were the default modes.  Right now I do not know exactly what is causing your issue.  My recommendation has been to upgrade to latest API for libraries since I do not know if old libraries will work with 1.2 or 1.3.

Comment: @jdweng Hmmm, I see. Thank you for the help. I will try that and update the thread if I find an answer!